# How to add onClick event in Ant Design List Item?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to trigger function when i click list item but it doesn't in list item.
In My code.

```
                            {suggestions.length > 0 &&
                            <List
                                className={classes['address-suggestions']}
                                size="small"
                                bordered
                                dataSource={suggestions}
                                renderItem={suggestion => <List.Item onClick={handleSelect}>
                                    {suggestion.description}
                                </List.Item>}
                            />

                        }
```

Comment: What happens when you add `onClick={something}`?

Comment: seems like you could add the `onClick` to the render item aswell.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it can. My problem is using of react-places-autocomplete package,.

Answer (score 0):

This extended example from the documentation works for me:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { List, Avatar } from 'antd';

const data = [
  {
    title: 'Ant Design Title 1',
  },
  {
    title: 'Ant Design Title 2',
  },
  {
    title: 'Ant Design Title 3',
  },
  {
    title: 'Ant Design Title 4',
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <List
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item onClick={() => console.log(item.title)}> // <-- on click handler
        <List.Item.Meta
          avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
          title={<span>{item.title}</span>}
          description="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
        />
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Antd v4.x I did not find a way to bind my h4 element from List.Item.Meta title attribute to a onclick event handler, I just copied the generated HTML with their classes and replaced the List.Item.Meta with this generated HTML.

So I ended up with something like this in the JSX of my component:

```
        <List.Item actions={ListItemActions}>
        <Switch checked={isChecked} onChange={onSwitchChange} />

        {/* this was List.Item.Meta before */}
        <div className="ant-list-item-meta">
            <div className="ant-list-item-meta-content">
                <h4 onClick={() => editHandler(todo)} className="ant-list-item-meta-title cursor-pointer">{todo.title}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of copied HTML */}

        <DescriptionIcon />
    </List.Item>
```

I hope it helps